# Was there a playable helicopter in the first Grand Theft Auto?

Tags: grand-theft-auto

In the [very first Grand Theft Auto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_%28video_game%29), I remember there being a picture of a helicopter (I think it was in the instructions) but I never found it in the game. Did it exist and was it playable?

Comment: I believe that this was a 3rd party mod you could install.

Comment: We want proof or it didn't happen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a helicopter in the game and I believe it was seen in a single mission in the game.  However, you couldn't fly it yourself.